# Generic diff of objects that include lists with gdiff

Tags: haskell

I am trying to use **[gdiff](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/gdiff)** 1.1, a generic diff library for Haskell, to get a difference between two objects that happen to contain a list.  However, I am not able to get it to work and I think it is because I don't know how to define the instance of `Type FooFamily` for `[FooEnvVar]`.  Here is the code I have so far:

```
module Main where

import Data.Generic.Diff

data Foo = Foo { fooEnv :: [FooEnvVar] }
  deriving (Show, Eq)

data FooStr = FooStr String
  deriving (Show, Eq, Ord)

data FooEnvVar = FooEnvVar { fooEnvName :: FooStr }
  deriving (Show, Eq, Ord)

data FooFamily :: * -> * -> * where
  FooF :: FooFamily Foo (Cons [FooEnvVar] Nil)
  FooStrF :: FooFamily FooStr (Cons String Nil)

instance Family FooFamily where
  decEq FooF FooF = Just (Refl, Refl)
  decEq FooStrF FooStrF = Just (Refl, Refl)
  decEq _ _ = Nothing
  fields FooF (Foo fe) = Just (CCons fe CNil)
  fields FooStrF (FooStr str) = Just (CCons str CNil)
  apply FooF (CCons fe CNil) = Foo fe
  apply FooStrF (CCons str CNil) = FooStr str
  string FooF = "FooF"
  string FooStrF = "FooStrF"

instance Type FooFamily Foo where
  constructors = [Concr FooF]

instance Type FooFamily [FooEnvVar] where
  constructors = []   -- what should I put here?

main :: IO ()
main =
  putStrLn $ show ((diff a b) :: EditScript FooFamily Foo Foo)
  where
    a = Foo [FooEnvVar (FooStr "hello"), FooEnvVar (FooStr "world")]
    b = Foo [FooEnvVar (FooStr "hi"), FooEnvVar (FooStr "world")]
```

This code compiles with no warnings under GHC 8.0.1 with the `-Wall` option.  When I run this code, I would want it to show the differences between `a` and `b`, but instead it shows this output:

```
test_gdiff: Incorrect Family or Type instance.
CallStack (from HasCallStack):
  error, called at src/Data/Generic/Diff.hs:313:22 in gdiff-1.1-KTbM5AUQcBxD5ewDUGZ4O3:Data.Generic.Diff
```

In case it matters, I am using the Haskell2010 language with these extensions: GADTs, LambdaCase, MultiParamTypeClasses, OverloadedStrings, FlexibleInstances.

How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no direct support for polymorphic lists in gdiff.

For every type at which you use a list, you have to treat the list type and its constructors (`[]`, `(:)`) as parts of the family.

Here are declarations that should work for your example:

```
data FooFamily :: * -> * -> * where
  FooF       :: FooFamily Foo         (Cons [FooEnvVar] Nil)
  FooEnvVarF :: FooFamily FooEnvVar   (Cons FooStr Nil)
  FooStrF    :: FooFamily FooStr      (Cons String Nil)
  NilF       :: FooFamily [FooEnvVar] Nil
  ConsF      :: FooFamily [FooEnvVar] (Cons FooEnvVar (Cons [FooEnvVar] Nil))
  String     :: String -> FooFamily String Nil

instance Family FooFamily where
  decEq FooF FooF = Just (Refl, Refl)
  decEq FooEnvVarF FooEnvVarF = Just (Refl, Refl)
  decEq FooStrF FooStrF = Just (Refl, Refl)
  decEq NilF NilF = Just (Refl, Refl)
  decEq ConsF ConsF = Just (Refl, Refl)
  decEq (String x) (String y)
    | x == y = Just (Refl, Refl)
    | otherwise = Nothing
  decEq _ _ = Nothing

  fields FooF (Foo fe) = Just (CCons fe CNil)
  fields FooEnvVarF (FooEnvVar ev) = Just (CCons ev CNil)
  fields FooStrF (FooStr x) = Just (CCons x CNil)
  fields NilF [] = Just CNil
  fields ConsF (x : xs) = Just (CCons x (CCons xs CNil))
  fields (String _) _ = Just CNil
  fields _ _ = Nothing

  apply FooF (CCons fe CNil) = Foo fe
  apply FooEnvVarF (CCons ev CNil) = FooEnvVar ev
  apply FooStrF (CCons x CNil) = FooStr x
  apply NilF CNil = []
  apply ConsF (CCons x (CCons xs CNil)) = x : xs
  apply (String x) CNil = x

  string FooF = "FooF"
  string FooEnvVarF = "FooEnvVarF"
  string FooStrF = "FooStrF"
  string NilF = "[]"
  string ConsF = "(:)"
  string (String x) = show x

instance Type FooFamily Foo where
  constructors = [Concr FooF]

instance Type FooFamily [FooEnvVar] where
  constructors = [Concr NilF, Concr ConsF]

instance Type FooFamily FooEnvVar where
  constructors = [Concr FooEnvVarF]

instance Type FooFamily FooStr where
  constructors = [Concr FooStrF]

instance Type FooFamily String where
  constructors = [Abstr String]
```